# Three.js pixel perfect at z=0 plane

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to configure the camera in Three.js so that when a 2d object (line, plane, image) is rendered at z=0, it doesn't bleed (from perspective) into other pixels.

Ex:

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1), material);
plane.position.x = 4;
plane.position.y = 3;
scene.add(plane);
...
// Get canvas pixel information
context.readPixels(....);
```

If you example the data from readPixels, I always find that the pixel is rendering into its surrounding pixels (ex: 3,3,0 may contain some color information), but would like it to be pixel perfect if the element that is draw is on the z=0 plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `THREE.OrthographicCamera` for the 2d stuff instead of `THREE.PerspectiveCamera`. That way they are not affected by perspective projection.

Comment: I had tried that yesterday thinking the same thing, and yet I still had the same problem. Finally, figured out I still had antialiasing set to true. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Which pixels get rendered depends on where your camera is. If your camera for example t z=1 then a lot of pixels will get rendered. If you move your camera to z=1000 then you see, due to perspective, maybe only 1 pixel will get rendered from your geometry.